# How flexible is JAXB?

Tags: jaxb

I am considering using JAXB for XML parsing but I'm having a couple of issues so far that lead me to believe that it might not be flexible enough for what I want.

I'll be parsing XML that is provided by third parties to conform to an XSD that I'll publish. So I want to be flexible enough to handle files that don't have namespaces or specify an old version of the namespace and may in fact contain invalid elements.

Is this sort of flexibility possible with JAXB? At the moment it fails to parse if the namespace is not provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How flexible is JAXB?

Very

> So I want to be flexible enough to handle files that don't have
>   namespaces or specify an old version of the namespace and may in fact
>   contain invalid elements.

**NamespaceFilter**

Below is a SAX `XmlFilter` that can be used to apply a missing namespace.

```java
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/customer";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is an example of how you can apply the SAX `XMLFilter` with JAXB.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();

        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller
                .getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        // Parse the XML
        InputSource xml = new InputSource("src/blog/namespace/sax/input.xml");
        filter.parse(xml);
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html