# JAXB Unmarshalling Error, package-info file for no namespace?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am attempting to Unmarshall XML from a file using JAXB. I also have a web service.
I want to use no namespace, not the namespace defined by the web service.

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CustomerName"). Expected elements are <{http://www.ws.NET}CustomerName>
```

I think that the solution is to change the `package-info.java` file to use no namespace. Is this the correct approach? and what changes should I make to this file?
The `package-info.java` file looks as follows:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.ws.NET", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package mynewpackage;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you say local namespace do you mean no namespace?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, yes correct, I mean no namespace. I have found a solution - namespace =""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a JAXB model that is annotated to be namespace qualified and you want to unmarshal XML that isn't there are a couple of options.

### If You Can Change the Model

You may just need to remove the `@XmlSchema` annotation from the `package-info` class.  If there are no other package level annotations you could remove the whole class.  Note that namespace information may also be specified on other annotations such as `@XmlElement`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

### If You Can't Change The Model

If you can't change the JAXB model to remove the namespace qualification then you can leverage a SAX `XMLFilter` to apply a namespace to the XML as it's being read.

- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14609597/how-flexible-is-jaxb/14610836#14610836

Comment: I removed the @xmlSchema annotation in the package-info class. (namespace=""). I'm not sure if this is an optimal solution, but it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Changing `QUALIFIED` to `UNQUALIFIED` will help if the top-level element (corresponding to the `@XmlRootElement` annotated class) *is* in the target namespace but its children aren't, e.g.

```
<ns:Response xmlns:ns="http://www.ws.NET">
  <CustomerName>Ian</CustomerName>
</ns:Response>
```

but this won't help if the top level (in this case `Response`) element is also unqualified.