# Getting Unexpected Element Exception while parsing JAXB class

Tags: java, jaxb

Can you please help me in solving this:

Here I am trying to unmarshal an XML file and getting the following error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"question"). Expected elements are <{http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/}question>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
```

The classes are:

## Question.java:

```
package JAXBTest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="question",namespace="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/")
    public class Question {  
    private int id;  
    private String questionname;  
    private List<Answer> answers;  
    public Question() {}  
    public Question(int id, String questionname, List<Answer> answers) {  
        super();  
        this.id = id;  
        this.questionname = questionname;  
        this.answers = answers;  
    }  
    @XmlAttribute  
    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    @XmlElement  
    public String getQuestionname() {  
        return questionname;  
    }  
    public void setQuestionname(String questionname) {  
        this.questionname = questionname;  
    }  
    @XmlElement  
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {  
        return answers;  
    }  
    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {  
        this.answers = answers;  
    }   

}
```

## Answer.java

```
package JAXBTest;

public class Answer {  
private int id;  
private String answername;  
private String postedby;  
public Answer() {}  
public Answer(int id, String answername, String postedby) {  
    super();  
    this.id = id;  
    this.answername = answername;  
    this.postedby = postedby;  
}  
public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getAnswername() {  
    return answername;  
}  
public void setAnswername(String answername) {  
    this.answername = answername;  
}  
public String getPostedby() {  
    return postedby;  
}  
public void setPostedby(String postedby) {  
    this.postedby = postedby;  
}  

}
```

## XmltoObject.java

```
package JAXBTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class XmltoObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {  

         try {  

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\u6026472\\Desktop\\question.xml");  
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBTest.Question.class);  

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  

      Question que= (Question) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  

            System.out.println(que.getId()+" "+que.getQuestionname());  
            System.out.println("Answers:");  
            List<Answer> list=que.getAnswers();  
            for(Answer ans:list)  
              System.out.println(ans.getId()+" "+ans.getAnswername()+"  "+ans.getPostedby());  




          } catch (JAXBException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
          }  

        } 
}
```

## package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/")
package JAXBTest;
```

## XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<question id="1" xmlns:cmn="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">  
        <answers>  
            <answername>java is a programming language</answername>  
            <id>101</id>  
            <postedby>ravi</postedby>  
        </answers>  
        <answers>  
            <answername>java is a platform</answername>  
            <id>102</id>  
            <postedby>john</postedby>  
        </answers>  
        <questionname>What is java?</questionname>  
    </question>
```

Comment: You either need to correctly prefix the xml elements with the declared namespace (`xmlns:cmn="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/"`) - eg. the question element would look like `<cmn:question>`. Another apporoach is to remove the prefix `cmn` (so that the namespace definition looks like `<question xmlns="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">`).

Comment: Hi Blaise, the question which has been answered, by the link you have provided is not feasible...it is using saxparser but i wanted to use only jaxb,

Comment: Hi fateddy, i cannot change the xml here its a restriction in my project...

Comment: Simply remove the `namespace` attribute from your `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Comment: removed and tried ..same issue

Comment: <env:ContentEnvelope majVers="3" minVers="2.3" pubStyle="Incremental" xmlns:cmn="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">
<env:Header>
<env:Info>
<env:Id>abc1</env:Id> 
<env:TimeStamp>ccd1</env:TimeStamp> 
</env:Info>
</env:Header>
<env:Body contentSet="OrganizationAuthority">
<env:Data xsi:type="proOrg:OrganizationDetailsItem">
<org:OrganizationFlags>
<IsOrganizationVerified effectiveFrom="11" providerId="1">true</IsOrganizationVerified> 
</env:ContentEnvelope>

Comment: The above is the sample for my xml..please help in solving this

Comment: look at the package-info.java - modify the namcespace here too (`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "")`). Then it should work - I've tested it and it worked!

Comment: actually i want to use the namespace here,,here it works for me , but for the sample actual xml ..it throws me the same error..even without using the namespace..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mapping, JAXB is expecting the XML to be:

```
<cmn:question id="1" xmlns:cmn="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">  
    <answers>...</answers>
</cmn:question>
```

Instead of what you are currently unmarshalling:

```
<question id="1" xmlns:cmn="http://data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">  
    <answers>...</answers>
</question>
```

The following are things you can do to fix this issue:

1. Fix the XML as I have indicated in this answer.
2. Remove the `namespace` property from the `@XmlRootElement` annotation so that your mapping matches the XML.
3. If you can't change the XML or classes, then their are things you can do to adjust the XML as you process it:

   - [How flexible is JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609597/how-flexible-is-jaxb/14610836#14610836)
4. You can have JAXB ignore the root element by using one of the unmarshal methods that takes a `Class` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Blaise...can you give me some idea if the xml is something like:
 
<env:ContentEnvelope majVers="3" minVers="2.3" pubStyle="Incremental" xmlns:cmn="data.schemas.financial.abc.com/Common/2009-09-01/">; <env:Header> <env:Info> <env:Id>abc1</env:Id> <env:TimeStamp>ccd1</env:TimeStamp> </env:Info> </env:Header> <env:Body contentSet="OrganizationAuthority"> <env:Data xsi:type="proOrg:OrganizationDetailsItem"> <org:OrganizationFlags> <IsOrganizationVerified effectiveFrom="11" providerId="1">true</IsOrganizationVerified> </env:ContentEnvelope>

Comment: @user3640657 - How does the XML in your comment relate to the XML in your question?

Comment: these are two different xmls..the xml in my project is quite huge and i cannot post here..so i tried a simple example ...by creating an xml with some namespace..but the comment i have is a sample of the xml which i am using it in my current project and i cannot modify the xml which is there in my project...

Comment: @user3640657 - This question should stay focussed on your simplified XML.  It looks like the larger XML should be a new question.  I won't evolve my answer here to address it, but I will try and help you out if you start a new question for it.